# Django display in html from views.py

Tags: python, html, django

I'm newbie in Django and i would like to have a little help please.
I have this code in views.py

```
def display_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort
    html = []
    for k, v in values:
        html.append('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (k, v))
    return HttpResponse('<table>%s</table>' % '/n'.join(html))
```

-------     return render(HttpResponse,'current_datetime.html',{'about': html})

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'current_datetime.html', {'current_date': now})
```

The part with '------' is added by me but i don't know if it's ok . The question is here , how should I display in the html file the return HttpResponse to show what meta is the user using.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}The current time{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>It is now {{ current_date }}.</p>
<p>You are using {{ HERE WILL BE DISPLAYED THE META FUNCTION, BUT HOW ??? }}</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
 <hr>
 <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I couldn't understand exactly how to ....
Thank you guys in advence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in settings.py add [read what this mean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    'django.core.context_processors.request',

)
```

and then, it is VERY important to load your custom templatetag

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

# NEW LINE
{% load  custom_tags %}

{% block title %}The current time{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <p>It is now {{ current_date }}.</p>
    <p>You are using {{ request|extract_meta }}</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
 <hr>
 <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Create custom template tags named `extract_meta` [here is doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/)

in templatetags/custom_tags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="extract_meta")
def extract_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort
    html = []
    for k, v in values:
        html.append('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (k, v))
    return '<table>%s</table>' % '/n'.join(html)
```